# How to bypass HTML form submission using jQuery (javascript)

Tags: jquery, forms, form-processing

I've a simple form

```
<form action="try.php" method="POST">
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input id="btn" name="" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I click the submit button, I want to submit the form only if a certain condition is met; and if not, the form will not be submitted (instead show and alert). **I do not want to change the markup here**. So how do I make it sure that, even though I've provided `<form action="try.php" method="POST">`, the form doesn't get submitted if the condition is not fulfilled?

I want to do something like the code below.

```
//jQuery code   
$("#btn").live('click', function(event) {
      if(<condition is true>){
          //Show message
      } else {
         //Submit Form
      }
});
```

Comment: You may want to use the `.bind` property instead of the `.live`.  Bind is good for attaching to known elements.  Live is useful for dynamic content that may be added to the page later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to submit the form, you can prevent the default action using [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
if(<condition is true>){
      event.preventDefault(); 
  }
```

or `return false;` It's better to do the former unless you also want to stop the event from bubbling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false;`. Then you can easily submit the form with `form.submit()`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add handler to form submit event, not to the button click.

Try something like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
  if(<condition is true>) {
    alert('Fill all fields');
    return false; // will cancel default submit
  }

  // do something before submit
  // if necessary
});
```